# Recurring Order pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I'm involved in a project that will feature daily or monthly recurring orders.  Rather than reinvent the wheel, can somebody point me toward a pattern for such an animal?

I'm thinking of some classic pattern like orders with line items.  Something that helps us clarify our thinking and design.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a structural or behavioral pattern? Can you explain the problem further? I'd start by getting this [book on design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book)) and just see if any of them sound like they could be adapted for the problem you are trying to solve.

Maybe composite as a structural pattern for handling orders/line items or visitor for processing orders that reoccur on monthly or weekly basis?

Comment: I was thinking of a structural pattern, or more accurately, something like Silverston's data models.  

I'm sure that I'm not the only guy to need to model a recurring order, I'm just not sure where to find the appropriate pattern/model.  Recurring Charge might be what I want.